# LINQ multiple where statement mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, function

This code works only if I complete the 3 fields:
website, author, and content.
I want to complete 1 field, 2 fields or 3 fields (non completed fields are null) and search according to that

```
var posts = from p in db.Posts
            where ((p.PostDate >= fd && p.PostDate <= td)
                && p.WebSite.Equals(WebSite)
                && p.PostAuthor.Contains(Author)
                && p.PostText.Contains(Content)
                || WebSite == null || Author == null || Content == null)
            select p;
```

I tried this code but don't working too:

```
var posts = from p in db.Posts
            select p;

if (WebSite != null)
{
    posts = from p in db.Posts
            where p.WebSite.Equals(WebSite)
            select p;
}

if (Author != null)
{
    posts = from p in db.Posts
            where p.PostAuthor.Contains(Author)
            select p;
}

if (Content != null)
{
    posts = from p in db.Posts
            where p.PostText.Contains(Content)
            //Count and date is missing                         
            select p;
}

return View("Index", posts);
```

I need like this for 1 parameter but for 3:

```
var posts = from p in db.Posts
            where p.PostTitle.Contains(searchTerm) || searchTerm==null
            select p;
return View(posts);
```

Comment: Explain not working. Are you getting an error? Or are you not getting the correct results?

Comment: I get the results only if i complete the 3 fields:
website + author + content
But if i complete only 1 or 2 of them i get all the posts
And if i leave all empty. all of them too
No error @JB06

Comment: Ok. If you leave them all blank, then returning all posts is the correct behavior. So that case is correct. Any reason you are using .Equals instead of == ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
var posts = from p in db.Posts
                where ((p.PostDate >= fd && p.PostDate <= td)
                       && ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(WebSite) || p.WebSite.Equals(WebSite))
                       || (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Author) || p.PostAuthor.Contains(Author))
                       || (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Content) || p.PostText.Contains(Content)))
                       )
                select p;
```

Comment: Doesn't work, this search any parameter separatly and not togeher, and if all of then null it doesn't show all the list. @yohanis

Comment: @yohanis I think you just want to remove the negation (`!`) form each null/empty check.

Comment: I have edited my answer above. Looks like you need to do ORs between the three. Please try the edited one. Plus, we don't need the negation as suggested by @DStanley.

Comment: @yohanis I understand your logic, finds all the fields together, not separatlly :(

Comment: var posts = from p in db.Posts
                        where ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(WebSite) || p.WebSite.Equals(WebSite))
                               && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Author) || p.PostAuthor.Contains(Author))
                               && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Content) || p.PostText.Contains(Content))
                               )
                        select p;

Answer (score 2):

Change your code to this:

```
var posts = from p in db.Posts
            select p;

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(WebSite))
{
    posts = from p in posts 
            where p.WebSite.Equals(WebSite)
            select p;
}

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Author))
{
    posts = from p in posts 
            where p.PostAuthor.Contains(Author)
            select p;
}

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Content))
{
    posts = from p in posts 
            where p.PostText.Contains(Content)
            //Count and date is missing                         
            select p;
}
return View("Index", posts.ToList());
```

An empty string is not the same as a null string.

**Edit:** you should probably execute the query before sending it to the view.

Using LINQ to Entities:

```
var posts = db.Posts.AsQueryable();

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(WebSite))
    posts = posts.Where(p => p.WebSite.Equals(WebSite));

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Author))
    posts = posts.Where(p => p.PostAuthor.Contains(Author));

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Content))
    posts = posts.Where(p => p.PostText.Contains(Content));

return View("Index", posts.ToList());
```

Comment: Much better than trying to single-line it in one where clause like the rest of the answers here attempt to do.

Comment: Thanks. I could clean it up more using fluent LINQ, but not sure if OP wants to use that.

Comment: Yeah, personally LINQ to SQL makes my skin crawl. I wish everyone would drop it and use LINQ to Entities.

Comment: The "cleaner version" also works just fine for LINQ over SQL as well.  Although, I do believe you will have a problem just doing `var posts = db.Posts;` as that returns a `DbSet<Post>`, and the rest of the queries will return `IQueryable<Post>`.  A simple solution is to do `var posts = db.Posts.AsQueryable();`

Comment: @RobertMcKee Good catch. I updated the answer with your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to prepare non filtered IQueryable object without selecting the output:

```
IQueryable<Post> query = from p in posts;
```

Then apply filter according to your filter conditions

```
if (webSite != null)
{
    posts = posts.Where(p => p.WebSite.Contains(webSite));
}
if (author != null)
{
    posts = posts.Where(p => p.PostAuthor.Contains(author));
}
```

Finnaly run query

```
var result = posts.ToArray();
```

Another approach is to create fulltext index on the table and search by fulltext in indexed columns. It has better results then searching in the three fields separately.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```
var posts = from p in db.Posts
                        where ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(WebSite) || p.WebSite.Equals(WebSite))
                               && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Author) || p.PostAuthor.Contains(Author))
                               && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Content) || p.PostText.Contains(Content))
                               )
                        select p;
```

Comment: Looks like you have used my answer. You should mark it as the correct answer rather than copying and pasting it - and put it as your own solution.

Comment: Is not your answer. I've changed  || and &&

Comment: So it's literally his answer with a small tweak. You should mark his as the answer and comment that you had to make a small tweak.

Comment: I did it , but is not clear. Is better to read my comment, there people can read the code better. Every response here works with this small tweak. 
Anyway, thank you all

Answer (score 0):

Just replace db.Posts with posts in the three conditional searches, so for the first one:

```
 if (WebSite != null)
        {
            posts = from p in posts
                    where p.WebSite.Equals(WebSite)
                    select p;
        }
```

Comment: Doesnt Work. Search 3 fields together but not separatlly or with nulls

Comment: @user3077648 - Instead of doesn't work why don't you try to understand why it doesn't work.  Just look at how obvious your question could be answered if you just actually thought about what was happening.

Comment: I understand that the query get all the values together but can't understand why if each statement is separatlly. I tryed to fix it during the last 4 hours